# Image not having a responsive margin-bottom

Tags: html, css, margin

This website I'm coding has a header with a portfolio. I want the persons "avatar" to be halfway onto the portfolio. Basically I want the avatar image to always be 50% down on to the portfolio div. The page is responsive so it shrinks accordingly.
The avatar image shrinks/resizes accordingly, however; the margin-bottom doesn't keep the same proportion. I always want it to be 50% below, onto the next div.
Here's the GIF. the start of it is how I want it, watch when I resize. Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsuXp.jpg

here's my code

```css
body {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="images/portfolio-avatar.png" class="banner">
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
  <img src="images/banner.png" class="banner">
</div>
```

Comment: @Shahnewaz hello you want the avatar to be fixed on the top border right? with 50% width?

Comment: Yeah, I want it to never leave that position.

Comment: check my snippet or codepen to resize your window,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use relative units (%) for the width of your avatar, as well as the padding-top, it will grow/shrink accordingly.

```css
body {
  width: 95%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 7.5%;
}

.avatar img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid white;
}

.portfolio img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/120/120
" class="banner">
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/400" class="banner">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.avatar {
  position: relative; 
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.avatar img{
    max-width: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
    
}

.portfolio img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
            <img src="https://www.ienglishstatus.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Sad-Profile-Pic-for-Whatsapp.png" class="banner">
        </div>
        <div class="portfolio">
            <img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/02/Etsy-Banners.png" class="banner">
        </div>
```

check this code, or you can check this here also.
find the link for codepen.
https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/qQQBMm

Resize the window and enjoy

Comment: That works and all, however, the avatar image doesn't resize. it stays the same size, while the banner gets smaller or bigger.

Comment: Dear I dont have a small image so I set a fixed max-width to avtar image, but if you will have a small image or image size of you need, then make avtar image max-width :100%; and see the magic, it was bound to give it a fixed with because it was a very big image. and yes one more important thing, image will only resize when it will not get the enough space around it to get fit. but if you page or device has the with more than avtar image's size then it will not resize. but anyhow if you want to resize it then use media queries.

Comment: If you find this helpful please mark this answer as correct